# Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider

Tags: android-studio

for this example

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(targetPdf);

if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
    intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileWithinMyDir);
    intentShareFile.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", uri));
    intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "sending file..."));
}
```

For images:

Change

```
intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
```

to

```
intentShareFile.setType("image/*");
```

It's work in Android 10, 11, 12

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider